# How to fix sending data via javascript/ajax/jquery to python server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I have the following Javascript trying to send data to a python server and trying to fix an error according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894765/cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the-remot)

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8082/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

But I still get the same error, but the data seems to be sent to the server when I pressed the button. However,

1. I still get the same javascript error as above
2. The error-function in the ajax call is used (I get a popup saying 'An error occurred')
3. On the python side I get the following output and error:

   ```
   b'time=00%3A00%3A00.00&date=zfgeztrze'
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 935, in handle_one_response
       self.run_application()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 909, in run_application
       self.process_result()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 895, in process_result
       self.write(data)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 741, in write
       self._write_with_headers(data)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 746, in _write_with_headers
       self.finalize_headers()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 689, in finalize_headers
       total_len = sum(len(chunk) for chunk in self.result)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 689, in <genexpr>
       total_len = sum(len(chunk) for chunk in self.result)
   TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
   Mon Jul 24 11:03:16 2017 {'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:8082', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REMOTE_PORT': '54480', (hidden keys: 25)} failed with TypeError

   127.0.0.1 - - [2017-07-24 11:03:16] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 21 0.002378
   ```

The full code of the html is here:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            processData:false,
            crossDomain:true,
            crossOrigin:true,
            contentType:false,
            url: 'http://localhost:8082',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            header:{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Horray the AJAX call succeeded!');
            },
            error: function(xhr, error) {
                alert('An error occurred.');
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="time" value="00:00:00.00"><br>
      <input name="date" value="0000-00-00"><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the python code on the server side:

```
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all() # makes many blocking calls asynchronous

def application(environ, start_response):
    if environ["REQUEST_METHOD"]!="POST": # your JS uses post, so if it isn't post, it isn't you
        start_response("403 Forbidden", [("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")])
        return "403 Forbidden"
    start_response("200 OK", [("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")])
    r = environ["wsgi.input"].read() # get the post data
    print(r)
    return r

address = "localhost", 8082
server = WSGIServer(address, application)
server.backlog = 256
server.serve_forever()
```

Instead of answering this question I also would appreciate if you could provide a *COMPLETE* and *WORKING* example on how to send data from the javascript-client to the python server, *and the other way around*.

I really have to use javascript on the client/web side in order to create graphics with `three.js`.

Comment: You would make life a lot easier for yourself if you used an actual web framework like Flask, instead of having to write raw WSGI functions.

Comment: I am looking for something easy and simple.I don't want to learn a new framework. But if the easiest way is to make it more complicated: Can you provide  a FULL and EASY and WORKING(!) example then, which I can have up and running in 15 minutes?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Ah flask is for python. I have it installed.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/ . Note, you are not actually doing any cross-domain requests, so you *don't need* any of that extra configuration.

Comment: What is a cross-domain request?

Comment: And the quickstart page only contains python code. What does the javascript code look like?

Comment: Your JS code is already fine, except you don't need the `crossDomain`, `crossOrigin`, and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. All this is for making Ajax requests to a domain that is not the same as the one that originally served the HTML page, which is not something you are doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149972/discussion-between-alex-and-daniel-roseman).

Comment: The basic example of flask works, but how to send data to and from the javascript? I cannot really see how to proceed now.